# Returns NaN values when calculating exponentially weighted moving average -Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The problem is simple:

```
import random, datetime, pandas as pd

    rows = 100

    random_times = pd.Series([datetime.datetime.now().replace(day = 1+ int(i / 60/ 24) % 28, hour= int(i/60) % 24, minute=i%60, second=random.randint(0, 59)) for i in range(rows)])
    a = pd.DataFrame({'values': [i + random.random()*50 for i in range(10, 10+rows)]}, index=random_times)
```

This is how the data looks now:

[image]

Now if I try to calculate exponentially weighted moving average while regularising the time:

```
    a['values'].ewm(span=50, freq='S').mean()# S for seconds
```

I get:

[image]

Why am I getting NaN?

Answer (score 1):

try this little monkey

```
 a['values'].resample('S').ewm(span=50, freq='S').mean()

Out[147]: 
2017-07-01 00:00:00     56.684041
2017-07-01 00:00:01     56.684041
2017-07-01 00:00:02     56.684041
2017-07-01 00:00:03     56.684041
2017-07-01 00:00:04     56.684041
2017-07-01 00:00:05     56.684041
```

Comment: What's the point of using "freq='S'" on data that's already sampled by second? If you remove that parameter, you'll get the same result.

Comment: yeah remove that. is this the output you expect ?

Comment: nope, it doesn't match with what ewm(freq=) should do: https://i.imgur.com/HjQX2SI.png

you can see that the result is different